# How to solve $y''(t)+λy(t)=0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

> How to solve this Sturm-Liouville problem:
>   $$y''(t)+λy(t)=0 $$
>   $$y(0)=y'(\pi)  ,y'(0)=y(\pi)$$

Would really appreciate a solution or a significant hint because I couldn't find anything

Comment: Can't you find the general solution of the ODE ?

Answer (score 2):

As the equation is linear with constant coefficients, we solve the characteristic polynomial

$$r^2+\lambda=0,$$ which gives the general solution

$$y(t)=c_+e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}t}+c_-e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}t}.$$

We also have

$$y'(t)=\sqrt{-\lambda}\,c_+e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}t}-\sqrt{-\lambda}\,c_-e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}t}.$$

Now plugging the given conditions,

$$c_++c_-=\sqrt{-\lambda}\,c_+e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}\pi}-\sqrt{-\lambda}\,c_-e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}\pi},$$

$$\sqrt{-\lambda}\,c_+-\sqrt{-\lambda}\,c_-=c_+e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}\pi}+c_-e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}\pi}.$$

This homogeneous linear system has non-trivial solutions when

$$\begin{vmatrix}1-\sqrt{-\lambda}\,e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}\pi}&1+\sqrt{-\lambda}\,e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}\pi}\\\sqrt{-\lambda}-e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}\pi}&-\sqrt{-\lambda}-e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}\pi}\end{vmatrix}=0$$

or

$$(\lambda+1)(e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}2\pi}-1)=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that $\lambda$ here is a real constant. In that case, break down the problem into three cases, depending on whether $\lambda$ is positive, negative, or zero. In the last case, you will get a linear function which is identically zero due to the boundary conditions.  In the first and second cases, the general form of solutions is given by $c_1 \cos(\sqrt{\lambda}t)+c_2 \sin(\sqrt{\lambda}t)$ and $c_1 e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}t}+c_1 e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}t}$, respectively. Applying the boundary conditions gives $2 \times 2$ linear systems for the coefficients $c_1, c_2$, which may be solved explicitly (and uniquely) conditional on the Jacobian being non-singular.

The boundary conditions also seem to give you a hint that you're probably looking for trigonometric solutions. But also, try and see how these behave when applied to exponentially growing and decaying  solutions  and whether that gives a triviality, as is often the case in such posed boundary value problems.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the first thing that comes to mind? maybe make a guess? define $$\mathbb{R} \ni t \mapsto y(t):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n$$ and see what happens when you plug that in, and start comparing coefficients

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is $e^{\pm\sqrt{-\lambda}}$ !

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, but why the downvote though ?

Comment: A downvote means "This answer is not useful". Recovering the solution from an entire series is a waste of time and will not help the OP. In addition, this is not an answer but a (misleading) hint.

Comment: yes true, but that's the basis for the exponential that comes out, it needs to be done at least once in any ode course. And the aim is not to arrive at a result fast using cheeky methods instead of trying to learn something through maybe "wasted of time" method @YvesDaoust

Comment: great, thanks for the downvote then, cheers !